# How to revert engineer number to datetime?

Tags: c#, silverlight, datetime

I knew this number **1317820569** is mean 9:16PM Oct 5, 2011.

I don't know where or how the date being converted to the number, but I do know it can be reconstruct back to the date that match with it.

Now, can some master here help me out to enlighten me how can it be done in C# ?

Thanks!

Comment: You'll need to figure out what the algorithm is to convert from teh number to the date (or vice versa first).  If you give us some other samples of numbers and matching dates somebody might be able to help you figure it out.

Comment: It's a UNIX epoch, translated to whatever timezone he's in. The GMT representation of it is `Wed, 05 Oct 2011 13:16:09 GMT`, so I'd guess he's GMT+8.

Comment: @shawchyn - Use my answer below, and use `DateTime.ToLocalTime` to convert to the current timezone.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It looks like a UNIX epoch, which is the number of seconds since 1st Jan 1970.

Here's how to do it:

```
DateTime date = new System.DateTime(1970, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0).AddSeconds(epoch);
```

You can do the reverse like this:

```
double epoch = (DateTime.UtcNow - new DateTime(1970, 1, 1)).TotalSeconds;
```

Comment: Don't you have to make sure that your epoch date is UTC?

Comment: Keep in mind this will result in a UTC timestamp, which you'll need to correct for. I would assume (based on the fact that you said 9.16pm) that you're running GMT+8

Comment: @JimMischel - Just commented to reflect that. Must've missed your comment by a second! :D

Answer (score 0):

Looks like it is the seconds since 1/1/ 1970

```
DateTime dt = DateTime.Parse("1970/1/1");
dt = dt.AddSeconds(1317820569); //result: 10/5/2011 1:16:09 PM
```

Answer (score 0):

This looks like a Unix timestamp.

```
static DateTime ConvertFromUnixTimestamp(double timestamp)
{
    DateTime origin = new DateTime(1970, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0);
    return origin.AddSeconds(timestamp);
}
```